# C# itextsharp.dll - SVG in PdfPTable

Tags: c#, svg, itext

Possible that I would embed SVG images in a PdfPTable?

Comment: this is completely unreadable - what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, iTextSharp doesn't support SVG format. You'd need to use another library to either convert it to one of the supported formats (JPEG, GIF, PNG, TIFF, BMP, WMF and EPS) before you insert it.